# How to create a database owned by an user other than SYSDBA?

Tags: firebird, firebird-3.0

When I issue an isql command:

```
create database "localhost:testdb.fdb" user milenio password "secret";
```

I get the following error:

```
Statement failed, SQLSTATE = 28000
no permission for CREATE access to DATABASE testdb.fdb
```

what am I missing? How do I grant the necessary permissions to user milenio?

Answer (score 4):

In Firebird 3 a user either needs to have (and be logged in with) the `RDB$ADMIN` role, or the user (or his current role) needs to have the `CREATE DATABASE` privilege to create a database.

See also the Firebird 3 Release Notes [User Privileges for Metadata Changes](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rlsnotes30.html#rnfb30-security-metadataprivs):

> ```sql
> GRANT CREATE DATABASE TO [USER | ROLE] <user-name> | <role-name>;
> ```

Or specifically, to grant this privilege to user `milenio`:

```sql
grant create database to user milenio;
```

followed by a commit.

This needs to be executed by SYSDBA or a user with the `RDB$ADMIN` role on the security database.